# How to ban a user for 60 seconds after he exceeded rate limit quota, in Fastify. ( fastify-rate-limit )

Tags: node.js, rate-limiting, fastify

My fastify rate limit is behaving abnormally.
I want to allow 20 hits in 60 sec and if you user surpasses the limit then they should be blocked for another 60 sec.

This is my code ->

> To use this you need to do " npm install fastify-rate-limit "

```
fastify.register(require('fastify-rate-limit'),
{
  keyGenerator (req) { 
    let requestUrl = req.raw.url;
    requestUrl = requestUrl.split('/');
    let apiName = requestUrl[requestUrl.length - 1].replace('/','');
    return req.raw.ip+apiName; 
  },
  max: 20,
  timeWindow: 1000*60,
  addHeaders: { 
    'x-ratelimit-limit': true,
    'x-ratelimit-remaining': true,
    'x-ratelimit-reset': true,
    'retry-after': true
  },
});
```

Scenario I want to achieve ->

User A requested for an API 20 time in 32 seconds that means he has now exhausted his quota of hits ( As he can only make 20 hits in 60 seconds ) and if now he make another request in the remaining 28 sec he should be blocked from making request for that API for another 60 seconds.

Comment: Is not working as you describe it?

Comment: yes it is not working, as I described

Comment: I'm missing the behaviour you are getting: does not the rate limit apply at all or is the blocked request with different timing?

Comment: different timing, I have a 60 sec time window and prior to that it is allowing the requests. and what I want is that after the allowed request it should block for 60 sec

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon I am using Ip address of the request as a part of the key here, but If 20 system are connected to the same wifi and there are hitting my site at the same time then they all will be blocked just after the first request because they all have the same public ip address and that is the address of the Hub/router, and this is a problem, can you suggest a better way to identify a system uniquely in this network so I can provide each system with a rate limit of 20 hits in one min instead of 20 hits for the whole network in one min.?

Comment: Do you have control on the client? I think it should send a custom header with a unique code per device or I would use the userId if your service is authenticated

Answer (score 0):

you can't archive it without implementing your own [`customStorage`](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-rate-limit/blob/master/store/LocalStore.js).
The default memory implementation has a clock that opens when the `timeWindow` has pass away.
So you get 20 reqs every 60 seconds. it does not start to count 60 sec after reaching the limit

Moreover, I would upgrade the `keyGenerator` to:

```
return `${req.raw.ip}-${req.routerPath}`
```

Because that function can be tricked by `http://localhost/api?a=1`, `http://localhost/api?a=2` etc.. since the raw URL is mutating

Comment: I am not sure about how to create my own customStorage but I agree what you said about my Keygenerator function. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Check this out https://github.com/fastify/fastify-rate-limit/blob/master/store/LocalStore.js

Comment: for me req.routerPath is undefined. I checked it while debugging

Comment: What fastify version do you have?

Comment: fastify version is 2.15.1

Comment: Thats why: it is a fastify v3 feature. I would check your rate-limit plugin version because the actual is for v3